# error `unhashable type: 'Index'` on attempting to standardize columns in Pandas DataFrame with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex and columns that I want to standardize (rescale to between -1 and 1). When I attempt to do this, I encounter the error `unhashable type: 'Index'`. What might be going wrong and how might I proceed?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler = MinMaxScaler()

df[[df.columns]] = scaler.fit_transform(df[[df.columns]])
```

Comment: You're looking for `df[df.columns.tolist()]`, the `df.columns` is a list itself, so double brackets are not required. Alternatively, I'd recommend: `df[:] = scaler.fit_transform(df.values)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `df.columns` is a list already, double brackets are not required here. Since you're trying to replace all values in the dataframe, I'd recommend using:

```
df[:] = scaler.fit_transform(df.values)
```